# hashRouter push history regular route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router "5.3.3" and not sure how to navigate out of a hash router once I am inside it. i.e.

I have

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/profile">
    <profilePage />
  </Route>
  <HashRouter>
    <FormComponents>
  </HashRouter>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is a multistep form and the initial URL is something like `example.com/form` and on every stage i.e. when you add email and hit submit it will change the browser URL to `example.com/form#password` but on the last submission which is the verification step, I want to route to `example.com/profile`.
using the default `const history = useHistory();   history.push("/profile");` will just change the URL to `example.com/form/#profile`.

I tried using the default browser history object `history.pushState({}, "Profile", "/profile");` It navigates to the correct URL, but the app doesn't re-render.

Comment: Why are you using more than one router in your app?

Comment: I believe that's a common practice. The reason is that on every form action I want the UI to get a hash change instead of a location change.

Comment: It must be a common practice I'm unfamiliar with. In RRDv6 it's an invariant violation to nest routers. RRDv5 doesn't maintain this invariant though, it'll certainly let you do it. You might try a series of redirects within the hash router and when finished issue a back navigation back to the route in the browser router the user was on prior to entering the hash router.

Comment: Another thought might be to create a global history object the main/outer router uses (*i.e. `createBrowserHistory`*) and import and use *that* `history` object to issue the navigation action from within the inner router. The idea is to use the history object of the relevant router/routing context. I'll stand up a sandbox and test this idea out.

Answer (score 1):

One thought might be to create a global history object the main/outer router uses (*i.e. `createBrowserHistory`*) and import and use *that* `history` object to issue the navigation action from within the inner router. The idea is to use the history object of the relevant router/routing context.

Example:

```
import {
  Router,
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"; // v4

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const ProfilePage = () => (
  <>
    <h1>ProfilePage</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/form">Enter Form</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </>
);

const FormComponents = () => {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  const navigateToProfile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    browserHistory.push("/profile");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>FormComponents</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}step1`}>Step 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}step2`}>Step 2</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}step3`}>Step 3</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link onClick={navigateToProfile} to="/profile">
            Profile
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/profile">
          <ProfilePage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/form">
          <HashRouter>
            <FormComponents />
          </HashRouter>
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/profile" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-hashrouter-push-history-regular-route]